# How to draw smooth ellipse (circle) in Qt?

Tags: qt

I need to create QGraphicsItem for circle and I'm getting the output as the one which I attached along with my question. How do I draw smooth circle with good quality ? [image] Above is my code and [image] and above is my output. Please help me regarding this. I've tried Antialiasing and SmoothPixMapTransform of the QGraphicsView using QPainter property. But, still the result is same.

Comment: What is your OS and Qt version ?

Comment: From the screenshot, it's obvious that the OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: A copy of the code instead of a screenshot would be better.

Answer (score 0):

set Anti-aliasing render hint for view

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#renderHints-prop

Comment: Thanks for the reply and still the output is same.

Comment: [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#RenderHint-enum) states:  Indicates that the engine should antialias edges of primitives if possible. Maybe it aint possible with your GPU or your current graphic driver doesnt support it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your default rendering engine doesn't support antialiasing.

Try the `-graphicssystem raster` command line parameter to force the raster (software) rendering.

Try also the "basicdrawing" example of QtCreator to check how widgets are rendered.

Answer (score 0):

See [setStartAngle()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsellipseitem.html#setStartAngle) and [setSpanAngle()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsellipseitem.html#setSpanAngle) documentation:

> Sets the start angle for an ellipse segment to angle, which is in **16ths of a degree**.
>
> Sets the span angle for an ellipse segment to angle, which is in **16ths of a degree**.

It's highly probable that your 20 and 45 (e.g. 1.25° and 2.8125°) are not what you want.

Comment: That's right, but that's also pretty obvious from the screenshot, and also irrelevant to the actual question.

Answer (score -1):

To enable antialiasing, you should add the following line:

```
view->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing);
```

Result:

- Antialiased

  [image]
- Normal

  [image]

Comment: He tried that already: "I've tried Antialiasing and SmoothPixMapTransform of the QGraphicsView"